# Функция Split в C++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть ли в C++ функция подобия split в Python и как ей воспользоваться?

Comment: В языке и стандартной библиотеке нет. Есть в BOOST.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan Можно поподробней?

Comment: http://www.haikson.com/programming/cplusplus/boost-split-string-eml/